# What are the features that the public SO has, but Teams does not?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am evaluating SO for teams to be used in my company as a tool for "knowledge management" (from administrative questions to business related information).

The company currently used several products/extensions from Confluence, but since I am fairly familiar with two SE sites (SO and Politics) I am biased towards using SO for teams (as per slogan "Your team already knows and loves Stack Overflow").

In order to provide a solid case for SO for teams, I am interested in what familiar features from the public site it lacks. Unfortunately, these details are not illustrated [on the Teams presentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams).

From my point of view, the following are of particular interest:

- gamification (points and badges) as this can be used to raise engagement and it is something the company can use to reward top users
- review queues - most users are not familiar with SO and its quality standards which I want to maintain, so some of the queues would be very useful (e.g. First posts, Edit).
- (less important at the beginning) is [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) available?

Comment: first bullet is fulfilled in SO for Teams, third bullet definitely not (as that would make your companies Q and A's publicly available)

Comment: In the team I joined there are no review queues and almost everything is available at 1 rep, the only exception being the creation of bounties.

Comment: @RobertLongson - good to know. However, as one used to SO, how can I efficiently check posts that need reviewing?

Comment: Teams will likely have far fewer posts per day, just look at the active ones, or even go through all of them. The charcoal team has 160 questions since it was created, and it's one of  the earliest teams to exist.

Comment: @Alexei The idea behind teams is its a small group of your peers, people who share a mindset, and therefore expects most lots to be acceptable to the rest of the team, and has a lower need for the kind of quality controls compelled by opening a site to millions of anonymous strangers on the internet, and at the same time has a much strong need to prevent internecine conflict.

Comment: @DanBron - yes, for relatively small teams it makes sense. My goal is to use for most persons in the company that require various information that typically requires lots of e-mails just to find out a person who knows about the issue. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is gamification actually a pro in the corporate environment? I'm not convinced that it is. Sharing knowledge is important but in your team surely you want them not to prioritise camping on a SO Team but actually working. Gamify the work!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> - gamification (points and badges) as this can be used to raise engagement and it is something the company can use to reward top users

These are available (though it's notoriously hard to get gold badges, except for Fanatic). In both Teams I joined, I have seen *some* of the same competitive spirit as on the public sites in the network, but all in good faith.

> - review queues - most users are not familiar with SO and its quality standards which I want to maintain, so some of the queues would be very useful (e.g. First posts, Edit).

These are not available, and probably not needed. The amount of traffic is (after the first onslaught) low; you will usually end up with a handful of users who read *everything* and since editing is already available at 1 reputation, posts that don't meet the quality standards are likely to be improved by others. And if somebody doesn't get the concept of Q&A, Stack Overflow style, chances are you can give feedback face-to-face, which will help tremendously.

> - (less important at the beginning) is SEDE available?

Nope, but there is [API access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams), and it works: I'm currently using it to send push notifications to my iPhone whenever there's a new Teams question. I guess you could use this to fill your own SEDE instance. @BrockAdams suggests they might build it in the future; since Teams is directly providing income to Stack Overflow (though I'm not sure it's already *profitable*), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s have a higher chance of being realized than normal.

Comment: I hope the fanatic badge does not take into account the non working days of the client country, because my understanding is that Teams is mainly for companies and will be used by employees during their working hours .

Comment: @GabrielDevillers it's called fanatic, not 8_to_5

Comment: @GabrielDevillers Cmon - give them all-in employees a reason to bring a camp bed for the next trimester ;)

Comment: I can imagine a "new posts since your last visit" queue-like interface being useful for Teams, specifically for those users who want to read everything.  But that would be quite different from the public SO review queues.

Comment: @Jeffrey actually, Teams *has* this functionality, in the form of a red dot next to questions with new activity since your last visit.

Comment: (I didn't mention that because the question asks for things that exist on the public site. One additional noteworthy feature is that you can ping *everyone* to have them look at a certain question, not just the people who already participated.)